# writer.writerow parsing XML to CSV

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, csv

As in my previous posts, I am trying to parse an XML file. the file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<library>
 <book>
  <title>Sandman Volume 1: Preludes and Nocturnes</title>
  <author>Neil Gaiman</author>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Good Omens</title>
  <author>Neil Gamain</author>
  <author>Terry Pratchett</author>
  </book>
 <book>
  <title>All the Lovely Things</title>
  <author>James Daniel Wise</author>
 </book>
 <book>
  <title>Beginning Python</title>
  <author>Peter Norton, et al</author>
 </book>
</library>
```

my Python script is:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom
import csv

def writeToCSV(myLibrary):
    with open('csvout.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        writer.writerow(['title', 'author', 'author'])
        books = myLibrary.getElementsByTagName("book")
        for book in books:
            titleValue = book.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].data
            authors =[]
            for author in book.getElementsByTagName("author"):
                authors.append(author.childNodes[0].data)   
            writer.writerow([titleValue] + authors)

doc = parse('library.xml')
myLibrary = doc.getElementsByTagName("library")[0]

# Call main function
writeToCSV(myLibrary)
```

This gives me this output:

```
title,author,author
Sandman Volume 1: Preludes and Nocturnes,Neil Gaiman
Good Omens,Neil Gamain,Terry Pratchett
All the Lovely Things,James Daniel Wise
Beginning Python,"Peter Norton, et al"
```

First I want to know why it puts quotes around the last line "Peter Norton, et al", and how to get rid of this! putting QUOTE_NONE in my code prevents this line from being returned at all.

Also, I want to add another column header 'key'. I want this to be populated by sequential numbers to give me this output:

```
key,title,author,author
1,Sandman Volume 1: Preludes and Nocturnes,Neil Gaiman
2,Good Omens,Neil Gamain,Terry Pratchett
3,All the Lovely Things,James Daniel Wise
4,Beginning Python,Peter Norton, et al
```

I have tried various things, like setting a "key" variable = 0 and then doing key=+1 in my def loop, but it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , try this(may be your expected program). A counter can be import from `itertools` to set as `key`

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse
import xml.dom.minidom
import csv
from itertools import count
c = count(1) #starts from 1
def writeToCSV(myLibrary):
    with open('csvout.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
        writer.writerow(['key', 'title', 'author', 'author']) #added key
        books = myLibrary.getElementsByTagName("book")
        for book in books:
            titleValue = book.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].data
            authors =[]
            for author in book.getElementsByTagName("author"):
                authors.append(author.childNodes[0].data) 
            writer.writerow([c.next()] + [titleValue] + authors)

doc = parse('library.xml')
myLibrary = doc.getElementsByTagName("library")[0]
```

**Then** why `quotes around the last line "Peter Norton, et al"`?

Since you are using `delimeter= ","` ,that name contains `,`.So `""` is for acting it as a single `string` in `csv file`

Comment: Genius, sir - thank you so much. I was completely unaware of the itertools lib and writerow didn't seem to like me adding an int into it's parameters.
This has solved my problem - THank you!!!
James